# Concatenate EF entity nested list titles

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, string-concatenation

I have very simple entities.

**My `Article` entity:**

```
public class Article
{
    public Article()
    {
        Tags = new HashSet<Tag>();
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

**`Tag` entity:**

```
public class Tag
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

**Relation between these entities (many-to-many)**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Article>()
    .HasMany(a => a.Tags)
    .WithMany()
    .Map(m =>
    {
        m.MapLeftKey("ArticleId");
        m.MapRightKey("TagId");
        m.ToTable("ArticlesTags");
    });
```

### Problem

I want to show articles table with tags separated by whitespace.

My query doesn't work:

```
var articles = from article in dbContext.KBArticles
               select new ArticlesListModel()
               {
                   Id = article.Id,
                   Title = article.Title,
                   Tags = string.Join(" ", article.Tags.Select(t => t.Title).ToArray<string>())
               };
```

Web-server show an error `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method "System.String Join(System.String, System.String[])" method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression"`

Comment: You have to enumerate the query before modifying it using unsupported methods.  Try adding `dbContext.KBArticles.ToList()` before the `select`

Comment: @Khan, you're right, but I already mark Damith's answer as right. Anyway thanks for comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `AsEnumerable` or `ToList` and retrieve the data first from the database and then process it.

```
var articles = from article in dbContext.KBArticles.AsEnumerable()
               select new ArticlesListModel()
               {
                   Id = article.Id,
                   Title = article.Title,
                   Tags = string.Join(" ", article.Tags.Select(t => t.Title).ToArray<string>())
               };
```

Comment: Thanks! Very simple solution :)